# I'm Getting an Exception about Connecting My SQL Server

Tags: c#, mysql

```
    private void frmResibo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        market m = new market();
        string cs = @"Data Source =.localhost; Initial Catalog = thesisdb; User ID=root; Integrated Security = true";
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cs);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_itemlist", cn);
        da.Fill(m, m.Tables[0].TableName);



         ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("tbl_itemlist", m.Tables[0]);
         this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
         this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
         this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

         this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

    }
```

I Got an error like this in line `"da.Fill---`

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'

Comment: You are using C# SQL-server client to connect to a MySQL server.  https://www.google.nl/search?q=C%23+mysql

Comment: You need to install mysql connector and need to use its dll.  Connection class will be MySQLConnection

Comment: You are also missing con.open()

Comment: i tried putting con.Open() but still getting an error, also tried using MySQLConnecting and still the same. Help Please

Comment: `Data Source =.localhost` I think you just want `localhost` but `My SQL Server` is very ambiguous ... `System.Data.SqlClient` is for *Microsoft* SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string specifies "Data Source =.localhost"; usually you would either put "Data Source = ." or "Data Source = localhost" (both of which mean the same thing: the computer that it is running on). But with that dot in front of the localhost, it may try to look for a machine with the name ".localhost", which may explain why it can't connect to that SQL server.

Also note that your SQL connection and data adapter are disposable, so should be in "using" blocks.